# how to use command "sudo adduser test" with no password?

Tags: linux, shell

I edited *suders* file with permission 440

```
testsudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/adduser
```

but, when i use command 
`sudo adduser test` 
with user testsudo, linux ask me testsudo's password.

however, i edited suders file with `testsudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`
it works. 
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's

```
/usr/sbin/adduser
```

not

```
/usr/bin/adduser
```

But this really doesn't belong on SO. Voting to close.

Comment: "/usr/sbin/adduser", it works, 谢谢!

Comment: No surprises there ;}